# Missing references with Ngen.exe

Tags: c#, .net, ngen

I'm trying to compile a  .Net / C# 4.6 application with Ngen.exe.

My application is build as 64bits, so i use the x64 ngen.exe.

**I have a lot of these errors :**

```
Warning: System.IO.FileLoadException: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses dépendances. Windows ne peut pas vérifier la signature numérique de ce fichier. Il est possible qu’une modification matérielle ou logicielle récente ait installé un fichier endommagé ou dont la signature est incorrecte, ou qu’il s’agisse d’un logiciel malveillant provenant d’une source inconnue. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070241) while resolving 0xa00004b - ADODB.Errors.Clear.
```

What are your advices please ?

Thanks a lot,

Regards,

Comment: It is an ancient .NET 1.0 PIA.  Still present in any .NET install in the c:\windows\assembly\gac directory.  Just declarations for that old COM component, nothing worth ngen-ing.  Tends to happen on code that started life back in the VB6 days.  Not a real problem, keep moving.

Comment: But...i don't see my compilling exe....is it ok?

Comment: Pretty hard to guess what that might mean, you can't run Ngen.exe without seeing your .exe.  The files that it produces are well hidden.

Comment: but, the command is ngen install xxxx.exe and it will create a yyy.exe no ?

Comment: No.  You'll have to look in c:\windows\assembly in one of the NativeImages subdirectories to see the native image files back.  A shell extension makes that difficult.  You can always double-check with Fuslogvw.exe, log all native image binds.